# NSTableView reuse View Pool size

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, appkit, nstableviewcell

I was looking for leaked items on my project when I saw that an `NSTableView` had 35 views attached. I thought that it may be some bug I added to the project since the `NSTableView` doesn't show more than 10 items at a time, so I tried to figure out why it wasn't recycling.

After some more tries and a new project with just an `NSTableView` I found out that it did reuse previous views, but just when there were a lot of items to show: my project instantiated 72 items before recycling and the test one around 127 without even scrolling 1px:

[image]

Does anyone know why these big numbers when the `NSTableView` can't show them all?

Thank you.

Comment: To enable quick scrolling?

Comment: Maybe, but that would mean that it sometimes caches more than 18 times the number of views that fit on the NSTableView. Seems like way too much.

Comment: How many scroll by if you flick up as quickly as possible on a touchpad?   Or a touchscreen, not that I know where to get on for OS X...   It doesn't seem out of line for it to relate to how fast the views can be scrolled, not how many are visible.